# May an aggregate use an aggregate lookup service or should the business logik be in a domain service?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am developing a DDD software by using CQRS with event sourcing. Now I am trying to figure out where I should put my business logic.

I have a condition aggregate root which references a triggerId (trigger aggregate root). I also have a conditionGroup aggregate root which holds a list of conditionIds. And I have a watchdog aggregate root which holds a conditionGroupId.

The domain sends out a triggerReceived event when the trigger aggregates Create method is called. The triggerReceived event has the triggerId and a value property which should be checked by a condition which is linked to the triggerId in the condition aggregate.

I have a subscriber on the domain side which listens to this event. My plan is to retrieve all watchdogs in the subscriber and call a method watchdog.ShouldBark(triggerId, value). The watchdog then needs to lookup the ConditionGroup aggregate (it has the ConditionGroupId as property) and call ConditionGroup.DoesGroupMatch(triggerId, value). The ConditionGroup has to lookup all Condition aggregates (it has a list of conditionIds) and call the Condition.DoesConditionMatch(triggerId, value) method.

So each aggregate has to lookup other aggregates to access a business logic method which does some checks (no updates are done).

Or is it better to have some watchdogService in the domain and the watchdog service does all the aggregate lookups and has the business logic?

So my question is: Can an aggregate lookup other aggregates by using an interface (IAggregateStore) to do business logic checks (no updates because only one aggregate should be updated per event)?

Comment: The way i have seen Event source work with CQRS is that you get all the information you need to process a command in the command handler  and pass all the info down to the aggregate to apply the business logic which involves validation as well. In your scenario i am unable to clearly get the context of why you have so many aggregate, it looks to me you need to some validation on creating  a trigger which i think can happen inside trigger aggregate cant' it ?

Comment: It's a little to difficult to understand the major players and their connections, even though you have outlined the method calls verbally. Some sample or pseudo code would help, and you can point out the specific piece of code that is the focus of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is fairly incomplete, so this answer might be incomplete as well.
Based on your description -

> *I have a subscriber on the domain side which listens to this event. My plan is to retrieve all watchdogs in the subscriber and call a method watchdog.ShouldBark(triggerId, value).*

I can smell something very bad in your domain design. What is the purpose of *ShouldBark* method. It must change the state of your WatchDog domain. If that is the case you are going in the wrong direction.

Lets get the domains of your business first. ***Trigger***, ***Condition***, ***ConditionGroup***, ***WatchDog***.

> *I have a condition aggregate root which references a triggerId (trigger aggregate root).*

So, your code in trigger aggregate should look like this (You might have found some of my codes are pseudo-code)-

```
public class Trigger : AggregateRoot
{
    ...
    public void CreateTrigger(int value)
    {
        //You can also pass new guid for trigger from your service
        Guid triggerId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var @event = new TriggerReceived(triggerId, value);
        PublishEvent(@event);
    }
}

//this is your event
public class TriggerReceived
{
    public readonly int Value;
    public readonly Guid TriggerId;
    public TriggerReceived(Guid triggerId, int value)
    {
        Value = value;
        TriggerId = triggerId;
    }
}
```

Now get into the right direction. Instead of retrieving all watchDogs, subscribe your **Condition** Service to this event.

```
public class ConditionService
{
    public void When(TriggerReceived @event)
    {
        //re-hydrate your condition aggregate root from event store
        var condition = getConditionByTriggerId(@event.TriggerId);
        //if you want to retrieve condition based on Value you can do that here
        //var condition = getConditionByValue(@event.Value);
        if(condition is not null)
            condition.MatchTrigger();
    }
}
```

Then in your **Condition** aggregate -

```
public class Condition : AggregateRoot
{
    ...
    public void MatchTrigger()
    {
        //your business logic here
        ...
        //we know trigger value matched one condition, so raise the next event
        publish(new TriggerConditionMatched(this));
    }
}

//this is your TriggerConditionMatched event
public class TriggerConditionMatched
{
    public readonly Condition Condition;
    public TriggerConditionMatched(Condition condition)
    {
        Condition = condition;
    }
}
```

Based on this -

> *I also have a conditionGroup aggregate root which holds a list of conditionIds.*

we can also state that, every condition should have a property called **ConditionGroupId**. Subscribe your **ConditionGroup** Service to listen the event above -

```
public class ConditionGroupService
{
    public void When(TriggerConditionMatched @event)
    {
        //re-hydrate your condition group aggregate root from event store
        var conditionGroup = getConditionGroup(@event.Condition.GroupId);

        if(conditionGroup is not null)
            conditionGroup.MatchTriggerToConditionGroup();
    }
}


public class ConditionGroup : AggregateRoot
{
    ...
    public void MatchTriggerToConditionGroup()
    {
        ...
        //do some check here, your business logic

        //raise the next event
        publish(new TriggerConditionGroupMatched(this));
    }
}

//this is your TriggerConditionGroupMatched event
public class TriggerConditionGroupMatched
{
    public readonly ConditionGroup ConditionGroup;
    public TriggerConditionGroupMatched(ConditionGroup conditionGroup)
    {
        ConditionGroup = conditionGroup;
    }
}
```

Finally, based on this -

> *And I have a watchdog aggregate root which holds a conditionGroupId.*

You should have a watchDogId property in your **ConditionGroup** domain. So, subscribe your **WatchDog** service to listen ***TriggerConditionGroupMatched*** event -

```
public class WatchDogService
{
    public void When(TriggerConditionGroupMatched @event)
    {
        //re-hydrate your Watch Dog aggregate root from event store
        var watchDog = getWatchDog(@event.ConditionGroup.WatchDogId);

        if(watchDog is not null)
            watchDog.Bark();
    }
}

public class WatchDog : AggregateRoot
{
    ...
    public void Bark()
    {
        ...
        this.ShouldBark = true;

        //you should raise your next event
        publish(nextEvent);
    }
}
```

You might have found this a web of events and subscribers, but remember, event sourced systems should always be eventually consistent. In this way, you have log of everything happening to a **Trigger** or **Condition** Or **ConditionGroup** Or **WatchDog**.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed answer. I haven't thought about doing it this way. This really looks like a very promising way to handle the business logic instead of my initial plan. I will think about it and refactor my code.

Comment: The only problem I have is that I can only load aggregates from the eventStore by aggregateId. All lookups in this form getConditionByTriggerId(triggerId) cannot be performed. 

Maybe the TriggerAggregate should have a list of conditionIds vice versa to the ConditionAggregate which has a list of triggerIds. In This case I can lookup the TriggerAggregate based on the triggerId, get all conditionIds and can then access the ConditionAggregates from the eventStore.

But is this solution clean or is there any other way to handle that?

Comment: Do you have a m-m relationship between **Trigger** and **Condition**? Before solving any problem related to your domains further I would suggest you to read Udi Dahan's excellent post about [m-m relationship in DDD](http://udidahan.com/2009/01/24/ddd-many-to-many-object-relational-mapping/)